# Growth formula of $\frac{dy}{dt}=k(60-y)$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Suppose a student has 3 hours to cram for an exam and during this time wishes to memorize 60 facts. The formula for facts memorized per hour is $\frac{dy}{dt}=k(60-y)$ where $y$ is facts memorized, $t$ is minutes and $k$ is a positive constant. It is assumed that $y<60$ for all $t \geq0$.

If the student memorizes $15$ facts in $20$ minutes, how many facts will the student memorize in one hour.

So take the given formula and moving $dt$ over gives
$$dy=k(60-y)dt$$ 
now this is where I'm stuck because I don't know how to get the $y$ on the right over the the left. If I distribute the $k$ and the divide by $y$ I'm left with $$\frac{dy}{y}=60k-k$$ 
but I don't believe that this is the way to go about it.

Comment: A glitch in your last equation it seems. Please verify once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a differential equation, where the goal is to find $y(t).$ You can solve this one by separation of variables:
\begin{align*}
dy&=k(60-y)\,dt\\
\frac{dy}{y-60}&=-k\,dt\\
\ln|y-60|&=-kt+C\\
y-60&=Ce^{-kt}\\
y&=60+Ce^{-kt}.
\end{align*}
To find $C,$ you must plug in the information you know: $y(20)=15,$ to get
\begin{align*}
15&=60+Ce^{-k20}\\
-45&=Ce^{-k20}\\
C&=-45e^{k20}.
\end{align*}
This makes sense, as we must have $C<0$ to force $y<60.$
So we can write
$$y=60-45e^{k20}e^{-kt}=60-45e^{k(20-t)}. $$
Can you finish?

Comment: Does $k=-\frac{\ln(45)}{20}$?

Comment: Hmm. If you can assume $y(0)=0,$ you could solve for $k$. In that case, I get $k=\ln(4/3)/20.$